# Struts2 - The requested resource is not available

Tags: struts2, http-status-code-404

Somebody please help me to execute this very first Struts2 app.

web.xml` file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"       xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-  app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>Struts2FirstProject</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>

    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>

    </welcome-file-list>

    <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter- class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
       </filter>

       <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>

     </web-app>
```

Struts.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <struts>

    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="getHello" class="anvi.Hello">
            <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
            <result name="fail">/error.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>

    </struts>
```

anvi.hello:

```
    package anvi;

    public class Hello {
    public String execute(){
        System.out.println("Hello from execute");
        return "success";

    }
    }
```

Console is:

```
    9 Nov, 2012 6:16:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
    INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/lib/i386;C:\Program Files\PC Connectivity Solution\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin;C:\Eclipse\eclipse;;.
    9 Nov, 2012 6:16:55 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
    WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Struts2FirstProject' did not find a matching property.
    9 Nov, 2012 6:16:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
    9 Nov, 2012 6:16:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
    9 Nov, 2012 6:16:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
    INFO: Initialization processed in 4256 ms
    9 Nov, 2012 6:16:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
    INFO: Starting service Catalina
    9 Nov, 2012 6:16:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
    INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.32
    9 Nov, 2012 6:17:02 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
    INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [224] milliseconds.
    9 Nov, 2012 6:17:04 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger info
    INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts-default.xml]
    9 Nov, 2012 6:17:05 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger info
    INFO: Unable to locate configuration files of the name struts-plugin.xml, skipping
    9 Nov, 2012 6:17:05 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger info
    INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts-plugin.xml]
    9 Nov, 2012 6:17:05 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger error
    SEVERE: Document is invalid: no grammar found. at (null:3:8)
    org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Document is invalid: no grammar found.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper.parse(DomHelper.java:113)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadConfigurationFiles(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:949)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadDocuments(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:163)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.init(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:130)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:209)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:66)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:390)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:437)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:51)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:277)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:258)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:382)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4650)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5306)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    9 Nov, 2012 6:17:05 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger error
    SEVERE: Dispatcher initialization failed
    Unable to load configuration. - file:/D:/SOFTWARES/java/apache-tomcat-7.0.32/Struts2FirstProject/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:3:8
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:69)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:390)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:437)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:51)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:277)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:258)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:382)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4650)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5306)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: Unable to load file:/D:/SOFTWARES/java/apache-tomcat-7.0.32/Struts2FirstProject/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml - file:/D:/SOFTWARES/java/apache-tomcat-7.0.32/Struts2FirstProject/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:3:8
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadConfigurationFiles(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:954)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadDocuments(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:163)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.init(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:130)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:209)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:66)
        ... 18 more
    Caused by: Document is invalid: no grammar found. - file:/D:/SOFTWARES/java/apache-tomcat-7.0.32/Struts2FirstProject/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:3:8
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper.parse(DomHelper.java:115)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadConfigurationFiles(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:949)
        ... 22 more
    Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Document is invalid: no grammar found.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper.parse(DomHelper.java:113)
        ... 23 more
    9 Nov, 2012 6:17:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
    SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
    Unable to load configuration. - file:/D:/SOFTWARES/java/apache-tomcat-7.0.32/Struts2FirstProject/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:3:8
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:450)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:51)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:277)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:258)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:382)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4650)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5306)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: Unable to load configuration. - file:/D:/SOFTWARES/java/apache-tomcat-7.0.32/Struts2FirstProject/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:3:8
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:69)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:390)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:437)
        ... 16 more
    Caused by: Unable to load file:/D:/SOFTWARES/java/apache-tomcat-7.0.32/Struts2FirstProject/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml - file:/D:/SOFTWARES/java/apache-tomcat-7.0.32/Struts2FirstProject/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:3:8
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadConfigurationFiles(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:954)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadDocuments(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:163)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.init(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:130)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:209)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:66)
        ... 18 more
    Caused by: Document is invalid: no grammar found. - file:/D:/SOFTWARES/java/apache-tomcat-7.0.32/Struts2FirstProject/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:3:8
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper.parse(DomHelper.java:115)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadConfigurationFiles(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:949)
        ... 22 more
    Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Document is invalid: no grammar found.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper.parse(DomHelper.java:113)
        ... 23 more
    9 Nov, 2012 6:17:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
    SEVERE: Error filterStart
    9 Nov, 2012 6:17:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
    SEVERE: Context [/Struts2FirstProject] startup failed due to previous errors
    9 Nov, 2012 6:17:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory D:\SOFTWARES\java\apache-tomcat-7.0.32\webapps\docs
    9 Nov, 2012 6:17:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory D:\SOFTWARES\java\apache-tomcat-7.0.32\webapps\examples
    9 Nov, 2012 6:17:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
    9 Nov, 2012 6:17:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
    9 Nov, 2012 6:17:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@89dd')
    9 Nov, 2012 6:17:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory D:\SOFTWARES\java\apache-tomcat-7.0.32\webapps\host-manager
    9 Nov, 2012 6:17:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory D:\SOFTWARES\java\apache-tomcat-7.0.32\webapps\manager
    9 Nov, 2012 6:17:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory D:\SOFTWARES\java\apache-tomcat-7.0.32\webapps\ROOT
    9 Nov, 2012 6:17:07 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
    9 Nov, 2012 6:17:07 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
    9 Nov, 2012 6:17:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
    INFO: Server startup in 10008 ms
```

Image:
      [image: image 1]
      [image: image 2]
      [image: image 3]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add doctype declaration to your `struts.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">

<struts>
  ...
</struts>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Next time include only relevant part of your problem. Adding images in your case is slightly overkill ;). And accept/upvote answers if they helps you.

Comment: I want to point out that the log says exactly what the problem is:  SEVERE: Document is invalid: no grammar found. at (null:3:8)

Answer (score 1):

Add the library "commons-lang3-3.X", then it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Hello this problem is araised due to DTD tags.

try this is DTD tags:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
```

Regards,

nag kamma.

Answer (score 0):

hey guys ensure that if you put all struts2 jars in lib directory. else in case if add all jars as a user library, then goto project properties and in the deployment assembly click add and select java build path entries and select your user library(i.e.) struts2 library.