# Getting error running struts2 helloworld program

Tags: java, struts2

I m new in Struts2. Creating a hello world program using struts. When I run it got first screen where i put my input but when click on submit button giving following error.

Source of  this helloworld example: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/struts_2/index.htm

HTTP Status 404 - /HelloWorldStruts2/hello

---

type Status report

message /HelloWorldStruts2/hello

description The requested resource (/HelloWorldStruts2/hello) is not available.

---

Apache Tomcat/6.0.29

Suggest what is the issue?

Comment: Thats all what I am getting                                                                                                                                 HTTP Status 404 - /HelloWorldStruts2/hello

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Status report

message /HelloWorldStruts2/hello

description The requested resource (/HelloWorldStruts2/hello) is not available.


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Apache Tomcat/6.0.29

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13308920/struts2-the-requested-resource-is-not-available Also can you please post struts.xml file?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
 <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
 <package name="helloworld" extends="struts-default">
  <action name="hello" class="com.struts2.tutorialspoint.HelloWorldAction"
   method="execute">
   <result name="success">/HelloWorld.jsp</result>
  </action>
 </package>
</struts>

Comment: when i was implementing this. It was written to set some environment. wats does that mean??

Comment: Environment variables are used  to set Path and Java_Home variable to Jdk/jre which contains files that will be used by JVM during runtime.

Comment: Already set these variables.

Comment: This looks more like a basic struts2 setup issue. For future references, I have created a github project of an already setup structure of a struts2 project. Anyone can download and build on top of it [Heres the link](https://github.com/MSaifAsif/Struts2Blank)

Answer (score 1):

Got the solution.

In index.jsp there was `<form>` tag. When I changed it to `<s:form>` its working fine.

Or change from

```
<form action="hello">
```

to

```
<form action="hello.action">
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me, specific to the question. Tomcat 8 was used:

Make sure you have created the `classes` folder under `WebContent\WEB-INF`.
In that create the `logging.properties` file and add the following content to it. (It doesn't matter if the file jumps on its own to Java Resources > Libraries) :-

```
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].handlers = \ java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
```

Then in the location of Tomcat's `webapps` folder delete your `HelloWorldStruts2.war` file.

Now follow the site's instructions to Export your project to a new `HelloWorldStruts2.war` file (remember to overwrite the existing `.war` file with the same name if it's there).

Again, deploy this file by copying it to your Tomcat directory's `webapps` folder.

In the browser, go to `http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldStruts2/index.jsp` again, though I'm not sure it will work for sure this time.

But this time, watch the Tomcat server application's verbose output. You will get some kind of exception like this (leave out Warnings for now):

```
30-Mar-2014 17:39:29.273 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-7] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart Exception starting filter struts2 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils
       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:213)
       at org.apache.struts2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:102)
       ...
```

Seeing this, what I did immediately was copy the `commons-lang3-x.y.z.jar` to the `WebContent\WEB-INF\lib` folder, and then exported and deployed the project again.

This time, again the page wasn't showing, so I watched the logs and found out that Tomcat did not explicitly clear the contents of the `webapps\HelloWorldStruts2` folder.

After deleting both `HelloWorldStruts2` and `HelloWorldStruts2.war` and refreshing the `index.jsp` page in the browser, my project did work fine!