# Resource not available in Struts 2

Tags: java, xml, jsp, struts2, http-status-code-404

I am new to Struts and I want to execute HelloWorld program, but I am getting "Requested resource not available" error as soon as I write a `<filter>` tag in `web.xml`.

[image: Project hierarchy]

**`web.xml`:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
   xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
   id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

   <display-name>Struts 2</display-name>
   <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>

   <filter>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <filter-class>
         org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher
      </filter-class>
   </filter>

   <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**`struts.xml` :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">
<struts>
   <package name="helloworld" extends="struts-default">
      <action name="hello" class="sagar.practice.HelloWorldAction" method="execute">
            <result name="success">/HelloWorld.jsp</result>
      </action>
   </package>
</struts>
```

I added all required struts jars as a user library.

I am accessing index page as : `http://localhost:8080/practice/index.jsp`

If I remove `<filter>` tag from `web.xml` file I am able access `index.jsp` page, but if I add `<filter>` tag it is giving "Requested resource not available" error.

Comment: index.jsp is under WEB-INF? the same HelloWorld.jsp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should turn on `devMode` on via setting a constant in the `struts.xml`. This mode is used if you want to troubleshot some issues like yours. It's more informative because it outputs to the console errors that are hidden in the normal mode.

```
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
```

After turning it on you may discover that you have wrong or inconsistent library set deployed with your application. You might find a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils` printed to the console, then adjust your library set with missing jars.

The `commons-lang3-3.1.jar` is required to resolve error.

Comment: I changed welcome file from index.jsp to default.jsp in web.xml and tried but it is still giving the same error. And checked by removing welcome-file-list tag too but no result. And I checked it by modifying the url-pattern to "/*.action" but encountering same problem.

Comment: I removed project from server and added it again to server(cleaned also)

Comment: Can you access other pages or actions?

Comment: What is the server name? Does it have a version? Also I don't understand which servlet-api version you are deployed to?

Comment: my servlet-api version is 2.5. And I cannot access any pages or actions. I created a new hello.html page to test but I am unable to access that also. tomcat server 6.0.32

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52617/discussion-between-sagar-and-roman-c)

Answer (score 0):

Change this content in struts.xml with the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">
```

Reference Link  : [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13308920/struts2-the-requested-resource-is-not-available)

If you are using 2.0 or bigger version in struts. Use the below filter.

```
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
```

Comment: changed and checked with filter tag by adding and removing it, but it is giving same error

Comment: sorry, that also didn't help. Do these effect in accessing index page also? because I am not calling any action classes

Answer (score 0):

Do the following change in Web.xml

```
<welcome-file>/WEB-INF/index.jsp</welcome-file>
```

And in struts.xml

```
<result name="success">/WEB-INF/HelloWorld.jsp</result>
```

It May Help You.