# Up gradation issue while migrate the struts version 2.2.1 from struts 2.3.24.1

Tags: struts2

Server: Weblogic
IDE: Intellej IDEA

Hi, I'm trying to migrate the struts version from 2.2.1 to 2.3.24.1

Added the required jars for Struts version 2.3.24.1 by following the below URL's
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.struts/struts2-core/2.3.24.1
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.struts.xwork/xwork-core/2.3.24.1

but getting the following error:

```
Could not load user defined filter in web.xml: org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:213)
        at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.register(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:102)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:240)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.getContainer(Dispatcher.java:967)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

As error suggests "StringUtils" class not found in the Commons-lang3 jar but i already added the commons-lang3-3.2 jar

but still I'm facing the same error above i mentioned.

Added Jars in the pom.xml

struts2-core 2.3.24.1,commons-fileupload 1.3.1,commons-io 2.4,ognl 3.0.6,javassist 3.11.0.GA,freemarker 2.3.22,xwork-core 2.3.24.1,asm 3.3,asm-commons 3.3,commons-lang3 3.2,servlet-api 2.4,jsp-api 2.0,log4j 1.2.17

Could anyone suggest me how to solve this issue?

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError doesn't mean it can't find the class, it usually means it finds more than one class of that type and don't know which one to pick. Ensure you are including only one commons-lang3 library (manually open the ear/war to be sure), and that it's not already available in the server.

Comment: As suggested by  Andrea Ligios, I have deleted the multiple commons-lang3 versions in commons-lang3 library and maintained only required jar version in my local m2 repo library.
Particularly for this issue,i have replaced the commons-lang3-3.2 by commons-lang3-3.1 then it works for me without any issues . Thanks a lot Andrea Ligios for responding so quick.

Comment: You are welcome. Answer your own question and mark it as accepted, to help future visitors with the same problem ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resource not available in Struts 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23638610/resource-not-available-in-struts-2)